# Neo4j usually crashes when I close ssh connection

Tags: database, ssh, crash, neo4j

I am using Neo4j in my graduation project.Everything works fine in neo4j database.But, I have problem about the crashing database.I tried to fix that problem in the following segment of command:

```
/var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j console
```

When I run this command neo4j is working fine but when I close ssh connection, It will crash again.How can I fix that problem?

Thanks, Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `bin/neo4j start` to start it in the background

Actually you should install it as a service on your system. Something like

```
 sudo bin/neo4j install
```

Then it keeps running after you started it until you stop it again.

Comment: Yep, I understand it completely.Thank you Michael.